# merge ID of three data base to obtain multiples row

Tags: r, merge, row

I have 3 data base, in this three data base my sample ID varryig. But i want to  merge to obtain one data base with multiple row of the same ID but not the same values
This is whats i have

df1

| ID | tstart |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 2 | 4 |

df2

| ID | tstart |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 40 |
| 3 | 15 |

df3

| ID | tstart |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 80 |
| 3 | 80 |

this is what i want

| ID | tstart |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 40 |
| 3 | 15 |
| 3 | 80 |

now i want to create a new variable i have this

| ID | tstart | t stop | results 1 | result 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 20 | 5 | NA |
| 2 | 4 | 40 | 10 | NA |
| 2 | 40 | 80 | NA | 52 |
| 3 | 15 | 80 | 68 | NA |
| 3 | 80 | 100 | NA | 56 |

and i want a new variable to have this df :

| ID | tstart | t stop | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 20 | 5 |
| 2 | 4 | 40 | 10 |
| 2 | 40 | 80 | 52 |
| 3 | 15 | 80 | 68 |
| 3 | 80 | 100 | 56 |

Comment: @akrum number that  you see are wrong it's only to create an example. But for ID 1 for example he  participat at day 12 and he die at day 20 and his for example "biological result" is 5

Comment: @akrum so i'm so sorry, so i tried what you said for the second question and it's work!! thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `bind_rows` to bind the datasets and then get the `distinct` rows

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df1, df2, df3) %>%
   distinct()
```

---

For the second case, if the input already have the 'tstart', 'tstop', we could `coalesce` the 'result' columns

```
dfnew %>%
    mutate(result = coalesce(result1, result2), .keep = 'unused')
```

-output

```
  ID tstart tstop result
1  1     12    20      5
2  2      4    40     10
3  2     40    80     52
4  3     15    80     68
5  3     80   100     56
```

#### data

```
dfnew <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), tstart = c(12L, 4L, 
40L, 15L, 80L), tstop = c(20L, 40L, 80L, 80L, 100L), result1 = c(5L, 
10L, NA, 68L, NA), result2 = c(NA, NA, 52L, NA, 56L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: i have an other question, with this table

Comment: i want to create a new variable and moove the results for each time in this new variable                                                           this is what i have    :                                                                                                       ID Tstart Tstop lab1 lab2
1 0 40 35 NA    2
2 0 40 35 NA    2    NA
2 0 80 NA 45     NA  5
3 0 30 20 NA    5    NA

Comment: ok thank i'm going to do this right now sorry

Comment: @akrum i put my question after my first question, hope it's ok ! thank you so much